# Access sub-controls of custom control from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I created a custom control in Expression Blend which consists of multiple `TextBlock`s placed in a `Grid`. Now I added this custom control to my phone page in Visual Studio and want to access and change the text of these TextBlocks from C# code.

How do I access these sub-controls in code?

I thought I could do something like this:

```
MyCustomControl.TextBlock1.Text = "New Text";
```

But it's not that easy. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `MyCustomControl.TextBlock1` exists but is `internal`, not `public`.  You can use `MyCustomControl.FindName("TextBlock1") as TextBlock` to locate the resources by name instead.

Comment: That is exactly what I was searching for. It works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does `GetTemplateChild(string name);` work ? You should be able to use it, to access the elements of your control's template

Comment: Unfortunately it returns null. But even if it worked - I create multiple of these custom controls at runtime. Using the name won't help me in this case. I need to target one specific control.

Comment: if it's returning null : this may be a case where : either you spelled the child's name wrong, or maybe it's a matter of casting the type properly ?

Comment: I tried it again, once with Rick's `FindName` call and once with `GetTemplateChild`, both with the same name. FindName succeeds, GetTemplateChild returns null (I omitted casting and looked if it returned an object at all - it does not).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code both should work for your requirement:

```
Control subControl1 = (Control)MyCustomControl.Controls[0];
```

or

```
TextBox subControl1 = (TextBox)MyCustomControl.Controls[0];
```

Using any code you are able to access Text Property.
Always keep remember the hierarchy in your custom control and then try to access all control level-by-level.

If still you are facing any issue feel free to ask.